# Java jersey hello world returns 404

Tags: rest, maven, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am trying to create a REST api using jersey in a maven java project. But I always seem to get a 404 response from the server.

This is my java class:

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Pretty simple.

my web.xml file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>REST API</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>se.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Rest Maven Webapp</name>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But when I try to open `http://localhost:8080/rest/ws/login/hello` in my browser. I just get a 404 response.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is your application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jersey latest bundle 2.25.1 which is stable

add fallowing dependency and try again

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>

     <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>
```

If it does not work

create app using maven command line and compare the configuration

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp \
            -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
            -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example \
            -DarchetypeVersion=2.25.1
```